# Creating a doubly Linked List for an application class

Tags: java, algorithm, list, doubly-linked-list

I'm new programming and have run into some errors here.

First problem is: I keep getting a compiler error in DLLApp.java saying "method in class DLL cannot be applied to given types;". I understand what it's saying, because I'm giving it a string Argument, but I can't figure out how to actually make it the correct Generic type.

Secondly, since this is not compiling yet, I can't check my program, but how do my methods in DLL look? I'm still trying to understand the DLL Data structure.

**DLL class**

```
public class DLL<E>
{

   /** A reference to the first node in this DLL. */
   private Node<E> first;

   /** A reference to the last node in this DLL. */
   private Node<E> last;

   /**
    *  Construct an empty DLL.
    */
   public DLL()
   {
      first = null;
      last = null;
   }

   /**
    * Return the first element in this DLL, or null if DLL empty.
    *
    * @return  The first element in this DLL, or null if DLL empty.
    */
   public E getFirst()
   {
      return (first != null ? first.element : null);
   }

   /**
    * Return the last element in this DLL, or null if DLL empty.
    *
    * @return  The last element in this DLL, or null if DLL empty.
    */
   public E getLast()
   {
      return (last != null ? last.element : null);
   }

   /**
    * Return the number of nodes in this DLL.
    *
    * @return  The number of nodes in this DLL.
    */
   public int size()
   {
      int size = 0;

      for (Node<E> curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
      {
         size++;
      }

      return size;
   }

   /**
    * Add an element to the start of this DLL.
    *
    * @param elem  An element to add to the start of this DLL.
    */
   public void addFirst(E elem)
   {
      insert(elem, null);
   }

   /**
    * Add an element to the end of this DLL.
    *
    * @param elem  An element to add to the end of this DLL.
    */
   public void addLast(E elem)
   {
      insert(elem, last);
   }

   /**
    * Add a new element after the element 'prev' (or at the end of this DLL if
    * 'prev' isn't found).
    *
    * @param elem  A new element to add to this DLL.
    * @param prev  An element to add 'elem' after.
    */
   public void addAfter(E elem, E prev) //use search method then insert
   {
      //Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(elem, prev, next); //do i need?

      insert(elem, search(prev)); //not sure?
   }

   /**
    * Delete a given element from this DLL.
    *
    * @param elem  An element to delete from this DLL.
    */
   public void delete(E elem) //create node etc
   {
      //Use search then use back and forward links instead of this whole method
      while (first != null) //move through list
      {
         if (first == elem) //if the next element is the deleting number
         {
            //reassign nodes skipping the first so deallocated(I think problem)

            first.prev = first.next;
            first.next = first.prev;
         }

         first = first.next; //move through the list
      }
   }

   /**
    * Return a string representation of DLL to allow System.out.println(aList).
    *
    * @return  A String representation of this DLL.
    */
   public String toString()
   {
      String result = "[";
      for (Node<E> curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
      {
         result += curr;

         if (curr != last)
         {
            result += ", ";
         }
      }

      return result + "]";
   }

   /**
    * Return a string representation of all the elements in this DLL, in 
    * last-to-first order.
    *
    * @return  A String representation of this DLL in reverse order.
    */
   public String reverseString()
   {
      String result = "[";

      for (Node<E> curr = last; curr != null; curr = curr.prev)
      {
         result += curr;
         if (curr != first)
         {
            result += ", ";
         }
      }

      return result + "]";
   }

   /**
    * Find the first Node which contains the given element.
    *
    * @param elem  The element to search for.
    * @return The first Node containing the given element, or null if no Node
    *         contains the element.
    */
   private Node<E> search(E elem) //HELP
   {
      for (Node<E> curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
      {
         if (curr.element.equals(elem))
         {
            return curr; //am i returning the element like this?
         }
      }

      return null;
   }

   /**
    * Insert a new element after the element 'prev'.  If 'prev' is null then
    * insert 'elem' at the front of this DLL.
    *
    * @param elem  A new element to insert into this DLL.
    * @param prev  An element to insert 'elem' after. If 'prev' is null insert
    * 'elem' at the start of this DLL.
    */
   private void insert(E elem, Node<E> prev) //HELP
   {
      Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(elem, prev, null);
         //if list is empty, add to front
      if (first == null)
      {
         first= newNode;
         last = newNode;
      }
      else if (prev == null)
      {
         //addFirst(newNode);
         first.prev = newNode;
         newNode.next = first;
         first = newNode;
      }
      else if (prev.next == null) //if at end of list
      {
         prev.next = newNode;
         last = newNode;
      }
      else
      {
         newNode.next = prev.next;
         newNode.next.prev = newNode;
         prev.next = newNode;
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple container class which holds an element, and references to
    * previous and next Nodes.
    */
   private static class Node<E>
   {

      /** The element this Node holds. */
      private E element;

      /** A reference to the Node before this one. */
      private Node<E> prev;

      /** A reference to the Node after this one. */
      private Node<E> next;


      /** 
       * Create a new Node with the given element, adjacent nodes.
       *
       * @param elem  The element this Node holds.
       * @param prev  The Node which comes before this one.
       * @param next  The Node which comes after this one.
       */
      public Node(E elem, Node<E> prev, Node<E> next)
      {
         this.element = elem;
         this.prev = prev;
         this.next = next;
      }

      /** 
       * Return a string representation of this Node.
       *
       * @return A string representation of this Node.
       */
      public String toString()
      {
         return element.toString();
      }

   } // end class Node

} // end class DLL
```

**Test**

```
package lab15;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DLLApp
{

   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      DLL<String> dll = new DLL<String>();

      while (input.hasNext())
      {
         handleLine(input.nextLine(), dll);
      }
   }

   public static void handleLine(String values, DLL<String> list)
   {
      Scanner tokens = new Scanner(values);

      if (tokens.hasNext("[aesdpr]"))
      {
         char command = tokens.next().charAt(0);

         switch (command)
         {
           case 'a':

            while (tokens.hasNext())
            {
              String nextToke = tokens.next();
               if (tokens.hasNext())
               {
                  list.insert(nextToke, tokens.next());
               }
            }
            break;

           case 'e':

            while (tokens.hasNext())
            {
               String nextToke = tokens.next();
               if (tokens.hasNext())
               {
                  list.addLast(nextToke, tokens.next());
               }
            }
            break;

         case 's':

            while (tokens.hasNext())
            {
               list.addFirst(tokens.next());
               }
            break;
         case 'd':
            if (tokens.hasNext())
            {
               list.delete(tokens.next());
            }
            break;

         case 'p':

            while (tokens.hasNext())
            {
               list.toString(tokens.next());
            }
            break;

         case 'r':

            if (list.size() != 0)
             {
               list.reverseString(tokens.next());
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which method is giving the error? Doesn't the error also include the types? (Can you post the exact error?) Also, I suggest you only ask about the compiler error, preferably remove all code not applicable to it from your program so we're left with a very small program and a question that's more useful for future visitors.

Comment: The methods that are getting the error are in the DLLApp, all of the cases for the switch statement. I'm passing it a string when in the DLL class they require a type <E>. Not sure how to change this in my App class.

Comment: I see you've fundamentally changed what you're asking (in the broader sense, it's the same project, but compiler errors and logic errors are fundamentally different and should be asked about separately). Doing this doesn't really fit into the [se] Q&A model, especially if there's already an answer posted. You should rather accept an answer that helped you solve the problem you asked about, and post a new question with a different problem. As such, I've reverted these changes, but you can still find it backed-up under [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23073807/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of different errors.

You try to call `insert(String, String)`, which would correspond to `insert(E, E)`, but there's only an `insert(E, Node<E>)` method. You'll need to either call `search` to get a `Node<String>` object (and make it `public` / `protected` to allow this), or change `insert` to take `(E, E)` and call `search` from within that function.

`insert` is `private`, thus you can't call it from outside the class - it should be made `public` / `protected`.

`addLast` takes 1 parameter only - presumably you should just remove `, tokens.next()` from the call.

Neither `toString` nor `reverseString` takes any parameters. My guess would be that `toString` shouldn't be in a loop, and neither should obviously take a `tokens.next()` parameter.